# Unable to parse all XML tags in PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing, line

I am new to XML and PHP, and I am not able to parse all the tags. I tried looking for a solution and not able to find one.

### The XML file is -

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <widgetlist>
     <widget id='1'>
       <content page='page1'>
          <row type='header'>
         <col>
                 <h1>Avinash</h1>
                 <h3>Second element</h3>
             </col>
          </row>
          <row type='content'>
            <col>
                  <p>Is a php programmer</p>
                </col>
          </row>

         <row type='content'>
            <col>
                   <h2>Heading 2</h2>
                </col>
         </row>

         <row type='footer'>
           <col>
                   <small>Thank You</small>
               </col>
         </row>
      </content>
   </widget>
```

The PHP file is -

---

```
<?php
    $xml        =   simplexml_load_file("product.xml");
    $products   =   $xml->xpath("//*[@type]");

    var_dump($products);    

    for($i=0;$i<count($products);$i++)
    {
        print_r($i);
        $count  =   count($products[$i]->col);
        print_r("   ".$count);
        print_r("\n");
        $col    =   (array)$products[$i]->col;
        $tag    =   key((array)$products[$i]->col);     

        echo "<".$tag.">".$products[$i]->col->$tag."</".$tag.">";
    }
?>
```

---

Any kind of help or guidance will really be helpful. Thank you. And also, please help me out with the best practices in xml if possible, so that parsing would improve.

Answer (score 2):

closing tag for

```
  <widgetlist>
```

is missing in the xml file

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the final tag, widgetlist. Also it might be a good idea to create an XSD file and get PHP to check that the XML matches.

This can be achieved like this

```
$request = new DOMDocument();
$request->loadXML($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
if (!$request->schemaValidate('xml/Request.xsd'))
{
  ErrorReply("InvalidRequest", "Schema validation returned false");
}
```